# When user logged in it fetches his data only

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, pdo

I am new to android development and I am working on a project in which I want to display only user data when he logs in.

Here's my code after user logged in-:

```
public class UserProfile extends Activity {
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
    adapt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_view,R.id.textView1);
    profile pf = new profile();
    pf.execute();
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lv.setAdapter(adapt);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}




class profile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]>{
    Dialog pd ;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(UserProfile.this, "Loading", "Please Wait...");
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        List<NameValuePair> l = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String user = intent.getStringExtra("user");
        l.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",user));
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://172.31.147.141/test/json.php");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String result = null;
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(l));
            HttpResponse response = hc.execute(post);
            HttpEntity ent = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = ent.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"),8);

            while((reader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        }

        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            return jsonfetch(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        for(String ad : result){
            adapt.add(ad);
        }
    }
    private String[] jsonfetch(String result) throws JSONException{

        final String comp_id ="comp_id"; 
        String comp_type="comp_type";
        //String Availabletime="Available_time";
        String stat="stat";
        String Description="Description";
        String address ="address";
        //String name="Name";
        String username="username";
        //String com = "complaint";

        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
        String[] resultstr = new String[ja.length()];

        for(int i = 0; i<ja.length();i++){
            JSONObject obj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            int compid = obj.getInt(comp_id);
            String stats = obj.getString(stat);
            String desc=obj.getString(Description);
            String addr=obj.getString(address);
            //String nam = obj.getString(name);
            String user = obj.getString(username);
            String compty=obj.getString(comp_type);
            resultstr[i] = "Comp_id: "+compid+"\nComp_type: "+compty+"\nStats:"+stats+"\nAddress: "+addr+"\nName: "+user+"\nDescription : "+desc;
            }
            return resultstr;

        }
}
```

}

And, Here is my Php Code:-

```
 <?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
$username='root';
$password='';
$server='localhost';
try{
$sqlcon = new pdo ("mysql: host=$server;dbname=project ims",$username,$password);
$q1="Select * from f_c_r where username = :user ";

$sql=$sqlcon->prepare($q1);
$sql->bindparam(":user",$_POST['username']);
$sql->execute();
$results=$sql->fetchall();
$json=json_encode($results);
echo $json;
}
catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e){
echo $e;
}
}
?>
```

When I try to run through this , logcat shows

> 10-10 12:01:15.700: I/Timeline(28017): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@16a98ab1 time:68504901
>   10-10 12:01:16.596: E/SpannableStringBuilder(28017): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
>   10-10 12:01:16.597: E/SpannableStringBuilder(28017): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
>   10-10 12:01:19.556: I/Timeline(28017): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@16a98ab1 time:68508757
>   10-10 12:01:23.480: I/Timeline(28017): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.complaint time:68512682
>   10-10 12:01:23.552: D/AndroidRuntime(28017): Shutting down VM
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017): Process: com.complaint, PID: 28017
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.complaint/com.complaint.UserProfile}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at com.complaint.UserProfile.onCreate(UserProfile.java:42)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
>   10-10 12:01:23.554: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    ... 10 more
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017): org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017):    at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:96)
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017):    at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:108)
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017):    at com.complaint.UserProfile$profile.jsonfetch(UserProfile.java:114)
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017):    at com.complaint.UserProfile$profile.doInBackground(UserProfile.java:87)
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017):    at com.complaint.UserProfile$profile.doInBackground(UserProfile.java:1)
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   10-10 12:01:23.614: W/System.err(28017):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

.

Comment: Not a solution but - HttpClient is deprecated you must use HttpUrlConnection instead.

Comment: Yes , i know. And its light weight too.

Comment: if you guys better version then use volley,it comes with caching mechanism as well

Comment: Logcat result value so that, its easy to help you out.

Comment: @MayankKhursija, I am asking that print the result variable in doInBackground().

Comment: Its showing null and i know that result string is null . Why that so? i have data in my f_c_r table related to particular username @JitendraKumar.Balla